# SSRS Chart Title - change font size for a part of the title

Tags: reporting-services, font-size, typography, charindex

I have a situation in which I have developed a visual chart in SSRS
2012. The chart title is fixed -

**Schools Performance in MyCity** *(County, State, Country)*

(Remember, the above title is NOT dynamic, so the situation is easy to handle.)

(1) I need to keep the first part :

**Schools Performance in MyCity**   (left 30 characters) at a font size of 12, Bold

(2) I need to keep the second part starting from the bracket "(" and ending in the other bracket ")" :

*(County, State, Country)*  (all characters after the left 30 characters) at a font size of 8, non-Bold and italic.

I am not able to use multiple title boxes due to space constraint in the chart

I need to get the equivalent of some T-SQL string functions such as CHARINDEX, PATINDEX, etc. in SSRS. I am not too familiar with string functions inside SSRS.

Can anyone provide me a solution on how to achieve my goal?

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The function you are looking for is InStr(YourString, "StringYouAreLookingFor"), you can then use Left(String, 1), Right(String, 1), and SubStr(String, 1, 2). I would then add two expressions, one outputting the first string and one the second and adding your formatting to each expression as desired. As mentioned in the answer, you won't be able to format different parts of your title so a textbox will have to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way here is you delete your chart title and add a textbox above your chart. In this textbox you can write your text with the desired formating (**Home Tab > Font**). If SSRS rearanges the position of the textbox and the chart, put the chart and the textbox in a rectangle, so they stay where you place them.
As far as I know rich text or formating in the title is not possible.

Comment: Agreed. The title box will allow custom font/size/styling but it applies to the entire string. Some places SSRS will allow you to use HTML but this isn't one of them. You can also create a list with two rows, add your title to the top one and drag your chart into the second cell to ensure proper formatting (if needed).

Comment: If he has plain text in the textbox (no expression) he can style every letter different. If its an expression to upgrade the textbox to rich text. Then its possible to write html styles